# Why Can't `DSolve` Find a Solution for this ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, symbolic

I wanted to find a basis for the set of solutions of the following ODE.

$$y^{''}+\frac{1}{x^2+1}y^{'}(x)+\left[-1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right]y(x)=0$$

But when I try to use `DSolve` as follows

```
ODE = 
  Derivative[2][y][x] + 1/(1 + x^2) Derivative[1][y][x] + (-1 - 1/(1 + x^2)) y[x] == 0
DSolve[ODE, y, x]
```

**I get an endless evaluation!**

As far as I know, there is not any analysis issues which may cause difficulties to find a solution. So I am wondering what is wrong?

Then I tried Maple and it just gave the solution as

[image]

Comment: Does the Maple result count as a solution since it's given in terms of an integral?

Comment: @QuantumDot: I think it is better than nothing! ;)

Comment: Getting stuck in a loop is something that can happen with any mathematical software when integration is involved, some software just automatically times out though.

Comment: The `FullSimplify[]` version of this equation in the positive $x$ domain is  `(2 + x^2) y[x] == y'[x] + (1 + x^2) y''[x]` which is a Sturm‐Liouville equation. Potentially the methods explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sturm-LiouvilleEquation.html) will help.

Comment: @Young: Could you get an answer by that?

Comment: @Quantum, to be fair, *Mathematica* is not above giving integral solutions as well: `DSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[Sin[x]], y[0] == 0}, y, x]`

Comment: @Artes You may want to take part in the discussion here :) : https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1219/1871

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When `DSolve` runs a long time, it's probably because either `Integrate` or `Solve` is chewing over a tough problem.  Here's a way to make `Integrate` give up quicker, so that you can see if that is the problem.

*Note/warning:*
The code returns `Inactive[Integrate][...]` instead of an unevaluated `Integrate[...]`.  The latter seems preferable, but I was unable to figure out how to do it.  Luckily, the inactive version seems to work.

*Base code:*  The function `withTimedIntegrate` runs *`code`* with `Integrate` under a time constraint of *`tc`* seconds.

```
ClearAll[withTimedIntegrate];
SetAttributes[withTimedIntegrate, HoldFirst];
withTimedIntegrate[code_, tc_] := Module[{$in},
   Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate},
    Unprotect[Integrate];
    i : Integrate[___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] :=
     Block[{$in = True},
      TimeConstrained[i, tc, Inactivate[i, Integrate]]
      ];
    Protect[Integrate];
    code
    ]
   ];
```

OP's example:

```
withTimedIntegrate[{dsol} = DSolve[ode == 0, y, x], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
dsol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OP's example with an IVP:

```
withTimedIntegrate[
  {dsolIVP} = DSolve[{ode == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, x], 
  1] // AbsoluteTiming
y[1] /. dsolIVP // Activate // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Check:

```
NDSolveValue[{ode == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[1], {x, 0, 1}]
(*  1.83793  *)
```

Comment: (+1) Perfect illustration! :)

Comment: A slight shortening: `TimeConstrained[i, tc] /. $Aborted :> Inactivate[i, Integrate]` can be replaced with `TimeConstrained[i, tc, Inactivate[i, Integrate]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks!  .

Comment: Q1: What `$in` stand for? (In other words: What parameter changes into it?)    ._._.    Q2: What's the execution order of `i : Integrate[___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := 
 Block[{$in = True}, TimeConstrained[i, tc, Inactivate[i, Integrate]]]`?

Comment: @ooo Re Q1: It's now called [the Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656). It's used several times on the site, which you can [search for](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Villegas+Gayley).

Comment: Re Q2: 1. Match `Integrate[___] /; ! TrueQ[$in]`; `$in` is undefined (or should be), so `TrueQ[$in]` is `False` and `! TrueQ[$in]` is `True`; so this definition matches any `Integrate[..]`. 2. Then `Block` is execute which sets `$in = True`. 3. Then `TimeConstrained`, which executes the original `Integrate` command (represented by `i`) under a time constraint. 4. Now `$in` is `True`, so this def. does not match and the regular `Integrate` is executed. 5 If `Integrate` finishes in time, the result is returned; if not, the inactivated `Integrate` command is returned.

Answer (score 9):

With

```
$Version
(* 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016) *)
```

the code in the question produces the desired answer, although slowly,

```
(* {{y -> Function[{x}, E^x*C[1] + E^x*C[2]*Integrate[E^(-ArcTan[K[1]] - 2*K[1]), 
     {K[1], 1, x}]]}} *)
```

Computation time, as measured by `AbsoluteTiming`, is about 40 minutes on my PC.

**Addendum**

As is so often the case, `DSolve` performs much better when given some help.  Begin with the substitution, `y[x] -> Exp[x] z[x]`.

```
Unevaluated[D[y[x], {x, 2}] + D[y[x], {x, 1}]/(1 + x^2) - 
    y[x] (1 + 1/(1 + x^2))] /. y[x] -> Exp[x] z[x];
Simplify[% Exp[-x]] // Apart
(* ((3 + 2*x^2)*Derivative[1][z][x])/(1 + x^2) + Derivative[2][z][x] *)
```

One might think that `DSolve` could solve this greatly simplified ode in seconds, but in fact it takes 36 minutes!  (Perhaps, `DSolve` is searching for a solution that does not involve `Integrate`.)

```
DSolve[% == 0, z[x], x]
(* {{z[x] -> C[2] + Integrate[E^(-ArcTan[K[1]] - 2*K[1])*C[1], {K[1], 1, x}]}} *)
```

The obvious substitution `z'[x] -> w[x]` finally allows `DSolve` to proceed quickly.

```
%% /. {z''[x] -> w'[x], z'[x] -> w[x]};
DSolve[% == 0, w[x], x]
(* {{w[x] -> E^(-2 x - ArcTan[x]) C[1]}} *)
```

Back substitution and an additional integration then yield the desired result.

Comment: So it seems to be a system issue? I was using `10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)`

Comment: @H.R.  I just added the computation time on my PC to the answer, almost 40 minutes.  Did you wait that long?  If so, it must be that the newest version is more capable.  I do know that a lot of improvements were made to `DSolve` in version 10.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer and attention. Many thanks for that.  It seems that `DSolve` needs some improvement in the cases where solution can be represented in an integral form! :)

Comment: It seems that you just did the reduction of order method with the help of *Mathematica* for computations.

Comment: @H.R.  Yes, I wanted to obtain some insight into why `DSolve` took so long.

Comment: And the insight was this sentence "(Perhaps, `DSolve` is searching for a solution that does not involve `Integrate`.)"? Right? :)

Comment: @H.R.  Yes, although not a very useful insight.  Too bad.