# Kernel crash solving ODE (Murphy #50), version 11.0.1 on windows

Tags: differential-equations, crash

This ODE (#50 from Murphy's ODE collection book) causes kernel crash each time

[image]

Here is the code

```
ClearAll[y, x]
DSolve[ y'[x] == Cos[2 x] + (Sin[2 x] + y[x]) y[x], y[x], x]
```

Screen shot below.  Should this be tagged a bug? Does this happen on other platforms? I am using windows 7. I tried it on 10.4, and it also crashes there.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But on version 9.0, it does not crash, but it can't solve it:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple can solve it, but solution is complicated using HeunC special functions which Mathematica do not have

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But Book also gives one simple solution `y(x)=tan(x)`, which is easily verified to be true by Mathematica. (the other solution it gives is little more complicated).

```
eq = Hold [D[y[x], x] == Cos[2 x] + (Sin[2 x] + y[x]) y[x]];
Simplify[ReleaseHold[eq /. y[x] -> Tan[x]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Why does Mathematica kernel crash on this ODE?

**Update:**

Send bug report to Wolfram support, CASE:3806616 .

fyi, the book contains 2315 ODE's, which will take me long time to type and run. The current test report if you are interested is [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/Murphy_ODE/KERNEL.htm).  But it currently contains small number of ODE's from the book, will add more with time.

Comment: Linux v11, get's stuck, but doesn't crash.

Comment: The code crashes v10.3.1 and v11.0.0, both on Windows 64-bit

Comment: @Feyre what do you mean by 'stuck'? No solution or evaluation taking too long? For me, the code seems to crash the kernel 2-3 minutes after its evaluation.

Comment: @JungHwanMin I let it run for 10m, without result, I'm considering letting it run for an hour just to see if anything happens. It should be noted I have 16gb of RAM, which is still more than most today, which might have to do with it.

Comment: I would go head and send a report to support@wolfram.com so that they can investigate and look address this.

Comment: It ran to completion giving `Inverse` warning, but not giving the solution.

Comment: No crash (just a hang) for me on Mac v11.

Comment: I noticed when trying this on the Wolfram Cloud, version 11.3.0, it told me the computation was using too much memory, rather than taking too long. I guess `Integrate` is simply taking up too much memory when trying to calculate parts of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit too long for a comment. I think the hang is happening within `Integrate`:

```
Block[{Integrate},
  DSolve[y'[x] == Cos[2 x] + (Sin[2 x] + y[x]) y[x], y[x], x] /. {
    Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate]}
]
```

[image]

## Edit

Here's the solution using [`withTimedIntegrate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120364/why-cant-dsolve-find-a-solution-for-this-ode/120650#120650) (as Micheal E2 pointed out in the comments):

```
withTimedIntegrate[DSolve[y'[x] == Cos[2 x] + (Sin[2 x] + y[x]) y[x], y[x], x], 1]
```

[image]

---

And just for fun, here's a way to solve this ODE:

- Substitute `y[x] == v'[x]/v[x]` to get

  `v''[x] - Sin[2x]v'[x] + Cos[2x]v[x] == 0`
- Next substitute `Cos[x] == t` to get

  `(t^2 - 1)v''[t] + (2t^3 - t)v'[t] + (1 - 2t^2)v[t] == 0`
- Then substitute `v[t] == t w[t]` to get

  `t(t^2 - 1)w''[t] + (2t^4 + t^2 - 2)w'[t] == 0`
- Substitute `f[t] = w'[t]` to get the first order separable equation

  `t(t^2 - 1)f'[t] + (2t^4 + t^2 - 2)f[t] == 0`
- This equation is easily solved, and the solution is

  `{{f[t] -> (E^-t^2 C[1])/(t^2 Sqrt[1 - t^2])}}`
- One can then perform all the back substitutions to get the final answer, which is where some nasty integrals will come into play.

Comment: "This equation is easily solved", *MMA* doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: [`withTimedIntegrate[DSolve[..], 1]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120650/4999) gives a slightly nicer result, with only the intractable integral left in the answer. (+1)

Comment: @Feyre I should've tested before I said that... MMA get's tripped up on a hard integral. I've edited my post to get to a solution that is easier to solve.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks for pointing me to `withTimedIntegrate`!