# DSolve taking a very long time with my ODE and not giving a useful answer

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Evaluating with `DSolve` has taken ~50 minutes to complete when given this ODE:

```
DSolve[y''[t] == Sqrt[1 + y[t]^2], y[t], t]
```

> `{}`
>
> DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost.

I am not sure if it is a problem with my input.

The computation takes even longer with boundary values.

```
DSolve[{y''[t] == Sqrt[1+y[t]^2, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

The output fro this is the same as shown above.

Is there a problem with the way I am expressing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 11.2 I obtain

```
DSolve[y''[t] == Sqrt[1 + y[t]^2], y[t], t]
```

> $$ \text{Solve}\left[\left(\int_1^{y(t)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{K[1] \sqrt{K[1]^2+1}+\sinh ^{-1}(K[1])+c_1}} \, dK[1]\right){}^2=\left(c_2+t\right){}^2,y(t)\right] $$

in moderate time. Maple performs a similar result.

Comment: I have received the same without boundary values in 11.2. Out of curiosity, have you tried the problem with the initial condition y[0] == 0?

Comment: @Popoman218 : DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

```
DSolve[y''[t] == Sqrt[1 + y'[t]^2], y[t], t]
(*{y[t] -> C[2] + Cosh[t] Cosh[C[1]] + Sinh[t] Sinh[C[1]]} *)
```

evaluates the solution quite fast!

Using the correct ode `y''[t] == Sqrt[1 + y[t]^2]` the substitution `y'[t]->z[ y[t]]` separation of variables gives the equation

```
z[y] z'[y] == Sqrt[1 + y^2]
```

which can be solved

```
DSolve[z[y] z'[y] == Sqrt[1 + y^2], z, y]
(* {
{z -> Function[{y}, -Sqrt[y Sqrt[1 + y^2] + ArcSinh[y] + 2 C[1]]]}, 
{z ->Function[{y}, Sqrt[y Sqrt[1 + y^2] + ArcSinh[y] + 2 C[1]]]}}
*)
```

The antiderivative function of z is the solution y[t]!

Comment: Sorry, what is the MMA code?

Comment: Also, the Sqrt[1 + y'[t]^2] should just be Sqrt[1 + y[t]^2]. The long computation time still exists.

Comment: That's some pretty quick downvoting. I usually let folks have a chance to correct a mistake first. (And in the rare case I downvote, they can reply to my comment when they've addressed the problem; or explain why I'm all wrong.)

Comment: Looks like with one more step (solving for `y` in terms of `t`), you'll get the result @user64494 got, but without both sides being squared.

Comment: @ Michael E2: Thanks for your comment concerning the pretty quick feedback...

Answer (score 1):

From [Why Can't `DSolve` Find a Solution for this ODE?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120364/why-cant-dsolve-find-a-solution-for-this-ode/120650#120650), which might be considered a duplicate:

```
ClearAll[withTimedIntegrate];
SetAttributes[withTimedIntegrate, HoldFirst];
withTimedIntegrate[code_, tc_] := 
  Module[{$in}, 
   Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate}, Unprotect[Integrate];
    i : Integrate[___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := 
     Block[{$in = True}, TimeConstrained[i, tc, Inactivate[i, Integrate]]];
    Protect[Integrate];
    code]];

withTimedIntegrate[DSolve[y''[t] == Sqrt[1 + y[t]^2], y[t], t], 1]

(*
Solve[
 Inactive[Integrate][1/Sqrt[ArcSinh[K[1]] + C[1] + K[1] Sqrt[1 + K[1]^2]],
  {K[1], 1, y[t]}]^2 == (t + C[2])^2,
 y[t]]
*)
```

Comment: Other similar Q&A: [(134168)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134168), [(157675)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157675), [(161391)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161391), [(163917)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163917)