# Execution time is too long — Higher-order equations (Wolfram Documentation)

Tags: differential-equations

This question comes from: [Exact Higher-Order Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveHigherOrderExactEquations).

```
5 y[x] + 5 x y'[x] - y''[x] + y'''[x]
```

Execution time is longer than several minutes.

Of course, its result of `DSolve` is...

[image]

...so prodigious large that my computer took 155.493 seconds to calculate it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `withTimedIntegrate` from [Why Can't `DSolve` Find a Solution for this ODE?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120364/why-cant-dsolve-find-a-solution-for-this-ode/120650#120650), I prefer putting a time constraint on `Integrate`.  `DSolve` might call `Integrate` several times, and I only want to abort the long ones.  Aborting all of them might yield an inferior solution.

```
withTimedIntegrate[
  DSolve[5 y[x] + 5 x y'[x] - y''[x] + y'''[x] == 0, y, x],
  1] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.10949, {{y -> ... }}}  *)

ClearAll[withTimedIntegrate];
SetAttributes[withTimedIntegrate, HoldFirst];
withTimedIntegrate[code_, tc_] := 
  Module[{$in}, Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate}, Unprotect[Integrate];
    i : Integrate[___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := 
     Block[{$in = True}, TimeConstrained[i, tc, Inactivate[i, Integrate]]];
    Protect[Integrate];
    code]];
```

See also:

- [Kernel crash solving ODE (Murphy #50), version 11.0.1 on windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134168/kernel-crash-solving-ode-murphy-50-version-11-0-1-on-windows/134182#134182)
- [DSolve keeps running](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157675/dsolve-keeps-running/157679#157679)
- [No result from DSolve (evaluation keeps running)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161391/no-result-from-dsolve-evaluation-keeps-running/161398#161398)
- [DSolve taking a very long time with my ODE and not giving a useful answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163917/dsolve-taking-a-very-long-time-with-my-ode-and-not-giving-a-useful-answer/163925#163925)

Comment: Q: Why `MemberQ[%, _Integrate, ∞]` gets `False`? What to get `True`?

Comment: @ooo Because to keep the integrals from evaluating, they are inactivated.  Try `MemberQ[sol, Inactive[Integrate][__], \[Infinity]]`. You can also change the form with `sol = sol /. Inactive[Integrate] -> Integrate`.  Since they're inside `Function`, they won't evaluate, at least until the `Function` is evaluated, at which point they will run forever.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Congrats on hitting gold badges in `differential-equations`, `calculus-and-analysis` and `equation-solving` tags. You're the first one who win all of them.  Best regards!

Comment: @Artes Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Preventing `Integrate` from trying to find anti-derivatives speeds it up

```
res = Block[{Integrate}, Function[expr, expr /. Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate]][
                          DSolve[5 y[x] + 5 x y'[x] - y''[x] + y'''[x] == 0, y[x], x]]]
```

Or trying each integral for at most one second:

```
pos = SortBy[Drop[Position[res, Inactive[Integrate]], 0, -1], Minus@*Length];

Fold[MapAt[TimeConstrained[Hold[# // Activate // Evaluate], 1, #] /.
             Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate] &, #, #2] &, res, pos] /. Hold -> Identity
```