# Why is Mathematica having trouble with this first order separable ODE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

Why Mathematica 11.1.1 seems to hang on

```
DSolve[y'[x] == Log[1 + y[x]^2], y[x], x]
```

Since this ODE is separable, it becomes just an integration problem.

Mathematica knows that `Integrate[1/Log[y^2 + 1], y]` have no closed form solution as it returns *instantly* unevaluated the integration of the left side

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**The question is**: What else could possibly make it hang on this?

I know CAS  does not necessarily follow the same steps to solve problems as humans do by hand, so it must be trying something else and I am just curious what is Mathematica trying to do with this to make it seem to hang (I gave up waiting after few minutes).

Hand solution follows.

**Solve**

$$
         \boxed{y'=\log \left(1+y^2\right)}
$$
**Solution**

This is separable ODE of the form $y'(x) = p(x) f(y) $.
Moving $\left(\log \left(y^2+1\right)\right)$ to the left side gives

$$
            \frac{y'(x)}{\log \left(y^2+1\right)} = 1
$$
Integrating both sides

\begin{align*}
            \frac{1}{\log \left(y^2+1\right)} \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}y}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}     &= 1 \\
             \int \frac{1}{\log \left(y^2+1\right)} \mathop{\mathrm{d}y} &= \int 1\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} \\
             \int \frac{1}{\log \left(y^2+1\right)} \mathop{\mathrm{d}y} &= x + C_0
\end{align*}

The left side has no closed form solution, therefore solution can be written as
$$
                 \boxed{\int^{y(x)} \frac{1}{\log \left(\tau ^2+1\right)} \,d\tau    = x + C_0}
$$

Comment: If to change $y^2$ on $y$ in the rhs, the solution is given as `{{y[x] -> InverseFunction[LogIntegral[#1 + 1] & ][C[1] + x]}}'. So may be after obtaining the integral it is trying to apply `InverseFunction` here too.

Comment: Michael's [`withTimedIntegrate[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120650) can be useful here: `withTimedIntegrate[dsol = First[DSolve[y'[x] == Log[1 + y[x]^2], y[x], x]], 2]`