# DSolve keeps running

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to execute the following code.

```
g = 1
a = 1.4 + 4.4*x/Pi
V = Integrate[r a, x] 
DSolve[
  (V Sin[x] + H Cos[x]) y'[x] + y[x] (a r x Cos[x] + (g a r - H ) Sin[x]) == 
    g a Sin[x] (a^2/12 + r^2), 
  y[x], x]
```

`DSolve` in the above code keeps running indefinitely. Kindly help.

Comment: Are you even sure this DE has a closed form solution?

Comment: No. I developed the differential equation and now trying to find a closed form solution. With g=1 and a=CONSTANT it forms a exact differential equation for which I have extracted the solution. But for 'a' as above it keeps running indefinitely.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `Integrate` is hanging. If you don't care about unevaluated integrals, you could use [`withTimedIntegrate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120364/why-cant-dsolve-find-a-solution-for-this-ode/120650#120650).

```
g = 1;
a = 7/5 + 22/5*x/Pi;
V = Integrate[r a, x];

withTimedIntegrate[
  DSolveValue[(V Sin[x] + H Cos[x]) y'[x] + y[x] (a r x Cos[x] + (g a r - H) Sin[x]) == g a Sin[x] (a^2/12 + r^2), y[x], x], 
  1
] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]