# How to find this function?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find the function `f[x]` satisfying the condition

```
5 f[x] - (f'[x])^2 == x^2 + x + 4
```

I tried

```
DSolve[5 f[x] - (f'[x])^2 == x^2 + x + 4, f[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

I can not get the result for along time. How can I find it?

Comment: Any reason to think there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: If there is no closed form, you may solve it numerically, or if this is not acceptable, you can try to expand `f ` into a base of acceptable functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to blocking `Integrate` is to set a time constraint on it (see [Why Can't `DSolve` Find a Solution for this ODE?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120364/why-cant-dsolve-find-a-solution-for-this-ode/120650#120650)).

```
ClearAll[withTimedIntegrate];
SetAttributes[withTimedIntegrate, HoldFirst];
withTimedIntegrate[code_, tc_] := Module[{$in},
      Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate},
        Unprotect[Integrate];
        i : Integrate[___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] :=
          Block[{$in = True},
            TimeConstrained[i, tc, Inactivate[i, Integrate]]
            ];
        Protect[Integrate];
        code
        ]
      ];

withTimedIntegrate[
 DSolve[5 f[x] - (f'[x])^2 == x^2 + x + 4, f[x], x],
 5]
(* long implicit solution Solve[...] with unevaluated integrals *)
```

Comment: Yes, I guess you already know this. Sorry I placed it at the wrong place.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Block[{Integrate}, DSolve[5 f[x] - (f'[x])^2 == x^2 + x + 4, f[x], x] /. {Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate]}]
```

Or:

```
time = 1; res = 
Block[{Integrate}, 
Function[expr, expr /. Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate]][
DSolve[5 f[x] - (f'[x])^2 == x^2 + x + 4, f[x], x]]];
pos = SortBy[Drop[Position[res, Inactive[Integrate]], 0, -1], 
Minus@*Length];
Fold[MapAt[
TimeConstrained[Hold[# // Activate // Evaluate], time, #] /. 
  Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate] &, #, #2] &, res, pos] /. 
Hold -> Identity
```

Solution by `Maple 2021`:
[image]

[Transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) equations can't be solved analytically.

Answer (score 4):

There are two polynomial solutions: $f[x]=1+x+x^2$ and $f[x]=(13+4x+4x^2)/16$.

Define $f[x]=a x^2 + b x +c$ and equate coefficients...

Comment: I think, this solutions is also true if f[x] is a polynominal.